# Sketch curve $y = (4x^3-2x^2+5)/(2x^2+x-3)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I'm trying to sketch the curve

$$
y = (4x^3-2x^2+5)/(2x^2+x-3).
$$

I tried to find the first and second derivative but I don't know how to find the roots of these.

\begin{align}
y' &= \frac{-5-8 x-38 x^2+8 x^3+8 x^4}{(-3+x+2 x^2)^2}
&&\text{Fermat Theorem}\\
0 &=  -5-8 x-38 x^2+8 x^3+8 x^4
&&\leftarrow\text{Stuck}\\
y'' &= \frac{34+276 x-24 x^2+64 x^3}{(-3+x+2 x^2)^3} \\
0 &= (-5-8 x-38 x^2+8 x^3+8 x^4)(-3+x+2 x^2)
&&\leftarrow\text{Stuck}
\end{align}

I am currently learning Calculus I.

Comment: Could you include latex in your question? It's unclear (at least to me) what you're trying to do.

Comment: @IndyZa: Are you familiar with finding the roots of a cubic and quartic function http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function and  and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function? Both of these do not factor nicely. The cubic has one real root and two imaginary, the quartic has two real and two imaginary. You can plot the numerator of the cubic and quartic to see where they are or use the web sites above for the approach to finding the roots. Here is a plot courtesy of [*Wolfram Alpha*](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+%284x%5E3-2x%5E2%2B5%29%2F%282x%5E2%2Bx-3%29) Regards

Comment: @Amzoti I have never done the intermediate value theorem on the cubic function before I'll try take a look on it. Thanks :).

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the second derivative.

- Factorise the denominator to find vertical asymptotes.
- Ask yourself what happens when $x \to \pm \infty$ to find the horizontal asymptotes.
- Put $x=0$ to find the $y$-intercept.
- Look for the roots of the numerator to give you the $x$-interecepts.
- Solve $y'=0$ to give yourself the turning points.

Once you have all of these the sketch should be straightforward.